# How to represent prefixes and suffixes in a L2 context

Tags: punctuation, symbols

An Anki deck I've downloaded is representing a word as "o-miyage" and "おーみやげ". The deck isn't using any kanji - it's based on JFBP book 1, which doesn't teach any kanji. I've hidden the romaji, so I'm only seeing "おーみやげ". I know the second character is intended to represent a hyphen, but it looks confusingly similar to the "ー" in "ラーメン".

Is there any notation used in the context of teaching of Japanese as a non-native language (or even outside that context!) to indicate prefixes such as bikago or suffixes such as "-や"?

Answer (score 2):

Such hyphens should be *much* shorter than Japanese 長音記号 (long vowel marker). Here's how おみやげ and ラーメン should look in a dictionary entry (screenshot of goo辞書):

[image]

[image]

If you are really seeing a long bar as wide as a hiragana character between お and みやげ, it means the app you're using is bad. I can't help reading it as おおみやげ.

English em-dashes can be sometimes confusing, and Japanese people use a very long dash instead. See: [Is Japanese em dash equal to Latin em dash?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36601/5010)

Comment: Wait what ... ramen is German?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Oops, I copied [this rare ラーメン](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228788/meaning/m0u/) ...